# django how to get status count in single dictionary

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

> In my user table i have many user type and status (pending = 0,1 =
>   approved). i am getting the count like.

```
     user = {}
     user['pending'] = User.objects.filter(type=3,status='0').count()
     user['approved'] = User.objects.filter(type=3,status='2').count()
     user['blocked'] = User.objects.filter(type=3,status='4').count()
     print(user)
```

> Using this i am getting result in this way like :
>       {'pending': 0, 'approved': 1, 'blocked': 0}
>   what actually i need is i want this same result through a single query can any one please help me related this ?? thanks in advance

Comment: any suggestion related this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use `Count` aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset).

```
from django.db.models import Count


result = User.objects.filter(type=3, status__in=[0, 2, 4]).values('status')
                    .order_by('status')
                    .annotate(count=Count('status'))

# create dict
result_dict = {r.status : r.count for r in result}

# rename keys of dict
new_keys= {'0':'pending', '2':'approved', '4':'blocked'}
result_with_new_keys = {new_keys[key] : value for key, value in result.items()}
```

`result` will be a `QuerySet` with `status` and `count` fields.

Then, we create a `dict` from `QuerySet`, and then we rename keys to get the desired dictionary.

Comment: hi @narendra through this i am getting result like : <QuerySet [{'status': 2, 'count': 1}]>
 but i want result like pendingcount = 0,approvedcount=1 in this way

Comment: @Himani Please check updated answer. Added code to replace keys.

Comment: I tried this ---
 result = User.objects.filter(type=3, status__in=[0, 2, 4]).values('status').order_by('status').annotate(count=Count('status'))
        new_keys= {'0':'pending', '2':'approved', '4':'blocked'}
        result_with_new_keys = {new_keys[key] : value for key, value in result.items()}
        print(result_with_new_keys)
but it returning me the error : AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: @Himani my bad, didn't realize adding `filter` will return a `Queryset`, not a `dict`.